# Best practice for authenticating a website user on multiple domains

Tags: authentication, passwords

I've looked through and failed to find a question that answers this: apologies if I've missed something.

A user registers on my website at `example1.com` - and can then log into `example1.com`, of course.

I also have `example2.com` which my user can log into as well. It uses `example1.com`'s credentials. But if she wants to log into `example2.com` then she currently has to fill in a login form on `example2.com` to get authenticated.

And I'm just about to write `example3.com` which will work the same way - using `example1.com`'s account details.

**I'd like a user to be able to log into `example1.com` and be logged into both `example2.com` and `example3.com` as well.** (And similar to log out).

What's the way of doing this?

- Am I best using a slightly unwieldy redirect chain from `example1.com` to `example2.com` to `example3.com` when someone logs in, so that the correct cookie is set on each domain?
- Am I able to set a cookie that all three websites can see?
- Why do some websites appear to use an `auth.example.com` subdomain, and is there anything I can learn from that approach?

If it matters: authentication is to allow a user to post comments or jobs or things like that: no financial details are kept. Login cookies on my websites expire after 24 hours, and contain a unique token which is checked against a database on every pageload. Currently that unique token is also reset on every login (so you can see that hopping from `example1.com` to `example2.com` is a bit painful). I use PHP and am unlikely to be very keen on a library: more interested to understand what the best practice is here, and how best to build it.